# Flutter blurring BoxShadow

Tags: flutter, containers

I have a transparent Container and I have to apply BoxShadow for it but BoxShadow makes another element and fills the Container with my selected color. I just want some shadow around it

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you please add some code . I think you want a shadow for your border . but your Container filled with Shadow Color . am I Right?

Comment: try to use colors.transparent for the transparent container. If you use enable border property in decoration,you can still have the shadow around it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
   height : 120,
   width : 200 , 
   decoration : BoxDecoration(
        color : Colors.white.withOpacity(0.4),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
  )
 )
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.